# need to capture mouse position in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, dom

how do i capture the position of the mouse using javascript and the canvas?

when i go to this page:http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/mouse.html

they show this:

```
function init_mouse() {
  canvasMinX = $("#canvas").offset().left;
  canvasMaxX = canvasMinX + WIDTH;
}

function onMouseMove(evt) {
  if (evt.pageX > canvasMinX && evt.pageX < canvasMaxX) { //how can you access the canvasMinX when its out of scope?
//also, what is pageX? is it the coordinate of the mouse? if not, how do i get it?
    paddlex = evt.pageX - canvasMinX;
  }
}

$(document).mousemove(onMouseMove);
```

and finally, i need this to happen on mouse click. so i do:

```
$(document).mouseclick(onMouseClick)
```

is that it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best for a perfect explanation on how to implement it using JS: [JavaScript Capture Mouse X-Y Position Script - Quick-Take Mini-Tutorial](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html)

Answer (score 0):

> try this... hope it helps.

```
    $("#divClick").click(function (e) {
            var posX = $(this).position().left;
            var posY = $(this).position().top;
            var cursorX = (e.pageX - posX);
            var cursorY = (e.pageY - posY);
            //cursorX, cursorY is the absolute position of the mouse pointer
});
```